# Entity Framework: Table that holds common data for different multiply entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, mapping

I have got a lot of tables in my DB and one that needs to hold common data for all of them. How can I map these tables using EntityFramework CodeFirst so I could Lazy or Eager load such data using normal queries?

Here is what I mean:

Entities:

```
public class Table1 
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  ...etc data
}

public class Table2 
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }

  ...etc data
}

public class Table3 
{
  [Key]
  public string Id { get; set; }

  ...etc data
}
```

And a table with common data for all of them:

```
public class CommonDataTable
{
   [Key]
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Normally I would map this by creating a table like:

```
public class CommonDataMappingTable
{
  [Key]
  public Guid Id { get; set; }
  public string Mask { get; set; } // like: typeof(Table3).Name
  public string MappedID { get; set; } // like: Table3.Id.ToString()
  public virtual CommonDataTable MappedData { get; set; }    
}
```

But as soon as I am new to Entity Framework I just do not know how to map such relation in EF CodeFirst model.
Thank you for your time and sorry for my bad English.